# Multiple site collections at root of SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, site-collection

Is it possible to have multiple site collections at the root of SharePoint 2013? I would like to have the paths `www.host.com/TeamA, www.host.com/TeamB`, etc where **TeamA** and **TeamB** are site collections. I can do this using the root `'/'` as a wildcard managed path but Microsoft recommends against doing it.

Comment: so you already know that you can do it? what's your problem now?

Comment: yeah, I wouldn't recommend it. Just use an explicit path for each site collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant have more than one root site collections, and i dont think you can create 2nd site under "/" path. Once you created the 1st root level site collection then SharePoint will not give you option to create another one under the "/" path( i check from Central admin).

You can create the manages path as **"/TeamA and /TeamB"**.

Root site collection is required for certain sharepoint features. So if you want site collections as  `www.host.com/TeamA, www.host.com/TeamB` I would recommend to use the [Host Named Site collection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424952(v=office.15).aspx) options if managed path is not looking good.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261845(v=office.15).aspx